# What technologies and frameworks should a front-end Salesforce developer know?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm about to be assigned my first LWC coding tasks and I am preparing myself for it.

I went through  the [Sample Gallery](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/sample-gallery) and [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components). I also learned how to use various components from the [Component Library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components).

I am advanced in:

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript
- Apex

I can read [Aura Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_components.htm) and [Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro_what_is_it.htm).

I have very little or no knowledge regarding Node.js, Vue.js, React, Ruby.js, JQuery and other related technologies.

Can anyone who's experienced with Salesforce front-end development tell me, what else I should learn except what I've mentioned? Do I need to know React for example to develop components in Salesforce? Or am I okay with HTML, CSS, Javascript and components from the Salesforce Component Library?

Comment: This question is likely to produce opinion based answers so not a good fit with this community. IMHO you are best off simply adopting LWC (which is its own framework) and forget mixing in others. You will keep bumping into issues making them work together. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: @PhilW Hi. Thanks a lot. Honestly I don't have anyone I could ask, so even though I'd imagine my question would get downvoted, I hoped it wouldn't get closed. How likely is it that I'd have to deconstruct a component from a SLDS and recreate everything from the ground up using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Apex?

Comment: It depends. I would say that 95% of the time you can use the standard components if you need their functionality. It is when the requirements deviate the UX from standard SLDS and LEX that you have to mess about. But even then, it is just LWC (JS, CSS, HTML) and some Apex.

Comment: I would say, personally, you should push back on requirements that require a modified version of a standard component and point out a) variation makes it inconsistent and so harder for users to learn and understand and b) costs a lot more in the long term - instead of having Salesforce maintain the component you have to. Again, all opinion.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks a lot. I wanted to ask exactly about what you answered. I'd imagine that having a client that makes up difficult requirements may require some negotiations regarding whether to use SLDS and simplify the design or to complicate it and redesign everything in HTML and other mentioned languages. Is that correct?

Comment: SLDS is a predefined CSS styling library used in their components and in the component blueprints. Custom components should adopt SLDS as much as possible. SLDS is NOT the standard components.

Comment: You will need to develop custom components when standard Salesforce functionality leaves a gap compared with requirements. Use LWC with SLDS and, where possible/sensible, use standard components too within your own. Opinion only.

Comment: @PhilW Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. I still have some time to study so I understand it. Thanks for sharing your experience, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry: If you have good knowledge of HTML, CSS and Javascript, you will be in a very good position. All the other technologies you've listed are not common in the context of Salesforce.

But even if you are a frontend developer, some knowledge of the backend is useful. If I were you, I'd have a look at [Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database) and [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) as well. Trailhead has lots of material and is an excellent starting point to get familiar with Salesforce, including coding.

If you will solely focus on frontend, you could have a look at the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/), e.g. its grid mechanism.

Finally, get your preferred editor or development environment ready! According to experience, getting familiar with an IDE and all its plugins can take a lot of time. I'd say the majority of us Salesforce developers these days use VSCode, but if you prefer vi - everything is possible, just don't wait until you learn that you need somewhere to key your code in.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering. I realized I forgot to mention that I also know Apex and SOQL. I edited the answer. Can you please tell me how likely is it that I'd have to deconstruct the components from Lightning Design System into standard HTML, CSS and Javascript to build a component? I'd imagine that this would have to be the most difficult thing regarding components - having to leave the LDS library and reconstruct everything from the ground up.

Comment: No, no, you won't need anything like "deconstructing" standard components (saying this although I'm not even sure I understand what you mean)! We strive to use the Salesforce's standard components as much as possible, but in many cases have to fall back to regular HTML elements (which will be simple for you, as you already know them well), garnishing them with LDS.

Comment: IMHO this does not answer the question.

Comment: Felix, thanks for calming me down. I'm glad that SLDS work most of the time.